# Real time data base synchronization

Tags: real-time

I have 2 computers which are connected to each other via serial comunication.
The main computer is holding a DB (about 10K words) the computer is working at a 20Hz rate.
I need real-time synchronization of the DB for the other computer - if data is added, deleted, or updated, I want the other computer to see or get the changes in real-time.
If I will transfer whole the DB peirodicly it will take about 5 seconds to update the other side - which is not acceptable.
Spmeone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the other computer has to get the changes (i.e. insert, delete, update) via the serial link.
The easiest way to do this (but maybe impossible, if you can't change certain things) is to extend the database-change methods (or, if thats not possible: every call) to send an insert/delete/update-datagram with all required data over the serial link, which has to be robust against packet-loss (i.e. error detection, retransmission, etc.).

On the other end you have to implement a *semantically* equivalent database where you replay all the received changes.

Of course you still have to synchronize the databases at startup/initialization or maybe periodically (e.g. once per day).